# Bash script for deployment as a cgi

Tags: apache, bash, deployment, cgi

i have a bash script that copies and modifies a bunch of configuration files in my app running as a cgi for fast deployment and testing.

This script is in the public_html folder of my hosting and it works perfectly, permissions set to 755.

I am making other cgi scripts in a subfolder public_html/foo/bar.cgi and giving it 755 permission.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

# test if we are in the correct place
touch foo 2>&1

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '</head>'

echo '<body>'
echo '<p>Hello World</p>'
echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
echo '<hr/>'

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

This doesn't work, the server answers with a 403.
I have checked the folder permission, and set it to 755 and 777 without results

UPDATE: Changed name from test.cgi to testscript.cgi and it's woking now

Comment: What about the Apache configuration? Perhaps it limits from which folder cgi scripts can be executed?

Comment: I can't modify it because i am on a shared hosting plan, however it should be ok, because i was able to run 'Hello world' scripts from cgi-bin and another folders too. Maybe it's limiting the names however, i will try to find out, thanks!